# The vertex of a parabola is at (3,2) and its directrix is $x-y+1=0$. Find the equation of latus rectum.

Tags: conic-sections

The distance of vertex from the directrix is $\sqrt 2$

Further, the slope of the axis is $-1$

The focus is $(h,k)$

Then $$\frac{h-3}{\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}}=\sqrt 2$$
$$h=2$$

And 
$$\frac{k-2}{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}=\sqrt 2$$
$$k=3$$

The slope of latus rectum is 1

$$y-3=x-2$$$$x-y=-1$$

The answer given is $x-y=3$

What’s going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h$ and $k$ are not computed correctly. They should be,

$$h= 3+ \frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt2=4,\>\>\>\>k=2-\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt2=1$$

which yields $x-y=3$.

Comment: Okay, I get that my computation was wrong, but how exactly? The angle was $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, so the cos component will be negative

Comment: @Aditya - the angle $\frac{3\pi}4$ is the direction from$(h,k)$ to $(3,2)$, which means $3-h=\sqrt2\cos\frac{3\pi}4$ and $h=4$.